# MSSQL Server 2008 - Convert Nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

im using mssql 2008 and Im permanently failing to convert an nvarchar to numeric values.

Can you please advise? I have different solutions I found over the www, but all of them are failing with the error message:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 15 Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to numeric.

I have built an reduced example for demonstration purpose:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.#temptable 

create table #temptable(
col1 nvarchar(10),
col2 numeric(10,5)
)
insert into #temptable values ('0,5','0')

select *,convert(numeric(18,2),col1)   from #temptable

 UPDATE #temptable
 SET col2 = CAST(col1 AS numeric(10,5))
 WHERE ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1


SELECT col1
, CASE ISNUMERIC(col1)
WHEN    1 THEN  CONVERT(numeric(18,2),col1)  
ELSE 0.00
END

from #temptable
```

Comment: Try converting "0.5" instead of "0,5".

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason.. thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting / Casting an nVarChar with Comma Separator to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515688/converting-casting-an-nvarchar-with-comma-separator-to-decimal)

Comment: use CAST(col1  as numeric(16,7) for more precision

Answer (score 1):

I alreay found an strong hint whats going wrong... the issue seems to be related to the , as seperator while the SQL server expects an .

if you change the following line to:

```
insert into #temptable values ('0.5','0')
```

its working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1` which fails for a ton of cases like `ISNUMERIC('1e4')` or `ISNUMERIC('$')` or in your case, `ISNUMERIC('1,000,000')`. Don't use `ISNUMERIC` in this fashion.

Instead, try this...

```
 UPDATE #temptable
 SET col2 = CAST(col1 AS numeric(10,5))
 WHERE col1 not like '%[^0-9.]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `try_convert()` in SQL Server 2012+:

```
UPDATE #temptable
   SET col2 = TRY_CONVERT(numeric(10,5), col1)
   WHERE ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1;
```

SQL Server re-arranges expression valuation in a query.  So, the `CAST()` might be implemented before the `WHERE` -- resulting in the error.  You can make a similar change to the `SELECT` version of your query.

In SQL Server 2008, you should be able to do effectively the same thing using `CASE`:

```
UPDATE #temptable
   SET col2 = (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1 THEN CONVERT(numeric(10, 5), col1) END)
   WHERE ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1;
```

Note:  There may be cases where `ISNUMERIC()` returns "1", but the value cannot be converted  (for instance, overflow).  In that case, this version would still fail.

Comment: Not available in 2008, is it?

Comment: @scsimon . . . I also fixed the tag on the question.