# Convert string number to decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have several columns that are of a string format that are actually numbers but some of them are empty. How can I convert them to text - I am getting an error.

Here is my sample:

```
Select  
         MES_MACHINE 
        ,[TubeJobNo]
        ,LEFT (Customer_Name, 25) AS Customer
        ,Sales_Order_Line_No AS OrderNo
        ,[AFL_O2MES_SO_DJ].[Child_Job_Number]       
        ,CAST(Setup AS decimal) --- that worked
        ,ISNULL(FORMAT([FinalDataOp Completion],'N0'),'') 
        AS FinalDataOpCompletion --- that does not work, how do you convet this?
        ,ISNULL(FORMAT([JobFinishedWIP Issue Fiber Set]*FibersCount,'N0'),'') 
        AS TotalLengthConsumed
```

Sample data:

```
5,675
5,666
5,674
5,663
5,557
5,543
5,675
5,662
```

Here is the error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 18 Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Comment: please show use some sample data

Comment: and the error...

Comment: what is your error..?

Comment: 5,675 5,666
5,674 5,663
5,557 5,543
5,675 5,662

Comment: @SamSmith1986 please edit your question with additional information, don't add to the comments.

Comment: Here is the error: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 18
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @SamSmith1986 this information is critical to the question. You should [edit] your question, to put it in there.

Comment: Its probably the comma, just replace that `replace(datafield,',','')`

Comment: Rather than looking to convert the data when retrieving it, you should be looking to change the way your data is stored. If you don't do this, then every time you want to interact with the colum, you will have to convert the data, which will be very inefficient. For example, in a scenario where you needed to do something like `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourNumericColumn > 5000`.

Comment: @SamSmith1986 I've edited the question for you; but here is a page showing [how to ask a good SQL server question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). The easier you make it for people to replicate your problem, the more chance that you will get the help you need.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515688/converting-casting-an-nvarchar-with-comma-separator-to-decimal

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the thousand delimiter in the numbers. What you may want to do is to update the columns first.

```
update table
set [FinalDataOp Completion]=replace([FinalDataOp Completion],',','')
```

Then run your query again.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error as your number contains a comma, you first need to replace the comma then convert into an int. see below sample.

**This will work**

```
select cast(replace('5,675', ',', '') as int)
```

**This will give the error as you are getting -**

```
select cast('5,675' as int)
```

***Note:*** You can also use IsNumeric() SQL function to check whether the string is numeric or not before converting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created `#tem` table depends on your data

```
create table #tem (setup nvarchar(20))
insert into #tem values('5,675'),
('5,666'),
('5,674'),
('5,663'),
('5,557'),
('5,543'),
('5,675'),
('5,662')

SELECT convert(decimal(15,4), REPLACE(setup, ',', '.')) from #tem
```

actually the answer is

```
 SELECT convert(decimal(15,4), REPLACE(yourcolumname, ',', '.')) from yourtable
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. I ended up using the TRY_Convert function. Here the code example for anyone interested:

```
,TRY_CONVERT (int,[StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_O2MES_TubeJob].Primary_Qty) As [TargetLength] ,ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT (int, [FinalDataOp Completion]),'') AS FinalDataOpCompletion ,ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT (int,[JobFinishedWIP Issue Fiber Set]*Count),'') AS TotalLengthConsumed
```